# Cucumber Eclipse Plugin - Pretty Formatting is not supported

Tags: eclipse, cucumber, test-runner

I have following configuration setup

- Windows 10
- eclipse 2021-06 (4.20)
- Cucumber Eclipse Plugin (https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/cucumber-eclipse-plugin)
- Java 1.8

When I run my Test case using testRunner (pretty)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tp9vA.jpg), they are getting passed but not formatted properly. Anyone please advise.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UfpO1.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

This got resolved after installing following plugin, thanks for looking into.

https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/ansi-escape-console